# debian 8 chromium infected

Tags: chromium, malware, debian-jessie

I run on
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
            Kernel: Linux 3.16.0-9-686-pae
      Architecture: x86.

Under chromium, i regurlarly encounter the following problem : when i click on a link, a new tab opens on a website not related at all with the link. After 2 or 3 clicks on the link with the same weird effect, i finally reach the correct page.

I suspect a malware changing the target URL on the webpage. I also have firefox which is fine.

How can i find the malware ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of searching for malware, just uninstall with it's settings and download again. In another way, it will be time consuming.

```
sudo apt-get uninstall purge chromium-browser
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

And delete your config files under the .config/chromium in your home folder.

Comment: Could you try again these ?

Comment: I will but should i delete config file after purge and install ?

Comment: Actually purge deletes config files but i want to make sure of it. You can delete config files of chromium after purge and uninstall.

Comment: ok done. I will navigate a bit and see if the problem is solved and then award you if so

Comment: Seems to be allright. Good. Thks. I think deleting config files was the most efficient.